# How to print out the private key in ECDSA by using crypto++?

Tags: c++, crypto++

I am trying to use the Elliptic Curve DSA.

In the part of "Generate private key" in the following code which I am using crypto++ library, the private exponent is printed out in the console.

How can I print out the private key itself?

```
int main( int, char** ) {

    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    ByteQueue privateKey, publicKey, testKey;

    string message = "Do or do not. There is no try.";

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Generate private key
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA1>::PrivateKey privKey;
    privKey.Initialize( prng, secp256r1() );
    privKey.Save( privateKey );

    cout<<"the size : "<<sizeof(privateKey)<<endl;

    cout<<"output 1 : "<< privKey.GetPrivateExponent() <<endl;
    cout<<"output 2 : "<< std::hex << privKey.GetPrivateExponent() <<endl;
    cout<<"output 3 : "<< std::hex << &privateKey <<endl;
    cout<<"output 4 : "<< std::hex << &privKey <<endl;

    // Create public key
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA1>::PublicKey pubKey;
    privKey.MakePublicKey( pubKey );
    pubKey.Save( publicKey );

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

    // Load private key (in ByteQueue, PKCS#8 format)
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA1>::Signer signer( privateKey );

    // Determine maximum size, allocate a string with that size
    size_t siglen = signer.MaxSignatureLength();
    string signature(siglen, 0x00);

    // Sign, and trim signature to actual size
    siglen = signer.SignMessage( prng, (const byte*)message.data(), message.size(), (byte*)signature.data() );
    signature.resize(siglen);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

    // Load public key (in ByteQueue, X509 format)
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA1>::Verifier verifier( publicKey );

    bool result = verifier.VerifyMessage( (const byte*)message.data(), message.size(), (const byte*)signature.data(), signature.size() );
    if(result)
        cout << "Verified signature on message" << endl;
    else
        cerr << "Failed to verify signature on message" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you want to print it. See [Keys and Formats](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats) on the Crypto++ wiki. The [PEM Pack](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PEM_Pack) may also be useful for you.